# Configure Siri from Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, plist, siri

Trying to find ways to set up Siri through the terminal. The only thing I need is to uncheck "Enable Ask Siri" box. Can I make it by editing plist without whole Siri app shutdown?

[image: Just this box]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

plist responsible for this checkbox is called ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.assistant.support.plist

to change value you need to

- `cd ~/Library/Preferences`
- `sudo defaults write com.apple.assistant.support.plist "Assistant Enabled" 0`

restart System preferences by reopen the window